# Angular4 view not updating with data set in a setTimeout

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to update a progress bar with the importing of some data. I have the import delayed a second for each record (might not be the best way but this function isn't going to be used that often and this works.)

I have the import working, and applying the updated % to a variable but the view is not updating properly.

```
export class AddQuestionComponent {
    public completionPercent = 0;

    public readThis(inputValue: any): void {
        var file: File = inputValue.files[0];
        var myReader: FileReader = new FileReader();

        myReader.onloadend = function (e) {
           // console.log(myReader.result);

           let time = 1000;
           let count = 1;
           let data = JSON.parse(myReader.result);

           for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

             setTimeout(function () {
               // do something here
               count++;
               this.completionPercent = Math.round(100 * i / data.length);
               console.log(this.completionPercent);
           }, time);
           time += 1000;
       }

    };

myReader.readAsText(file);
}
```

The console outputs the updated % of `this.completionPercent` but the view never updates.

```
<div class="progress progress-sm mb-3">
     <div class="progress-bar bg-info" role="progressbar" [ngStyle]="{ 'width': completionPercent + '%' }" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
</div>
```

What am I missing/doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function () {
```

"breaks" `this`

Use instead

```
setTimeout(() => {
```

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

and instead of

```
myReader.onloadend = function (e) {
```

use

```
myReader.onloadend = (e) => {
```

Comment: when I use `setTimeout(() => {` then I get errors relating to this.completionPercent doesn't exist or it doesn't have access to it. "Property 'completionPercent' does not exist on type 'MSBaseReader'." so how can I access the parent class inside of the reader?

Comment: I missed `myReader.onloadend = function (e) {`. You have to use arrow functions everywhere where you want `this` to work (there are other ways like `...bind(this)` but you have to take some measures to keep `this` working.

Comment: I knew it was something simple I was missing. `myReader.onloadend = (e) => {` did the trick. thank you!